# Logit Gradient/Hessian derivations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to follow the algebra leading from the gradient function to the Hessian in Logistic Regression, but I can't quite understand where I have gone wrong.

I have the gradient function as:
$$
\sum_i^m \left[x_i\cdot \frac {\exp\{-\theta^T x_i\}} {1+\exp\{-\theta^T x_i\}} - (y_i-1)  x_i \right]
$$

After deriving the gradient, I'm trying to rearrange terms and simplify the expression...

First, we can note that the logistic regression model can be expressed as
$$
p(y=1|x; \theta) = \frac{1}{1+exp(-\theta^Tx_i)}
$$
Similarly, we can also show that
$$
p(y=0|x; \theta) = 1-\frac{1}{1+exp(-\theta^Tx_i)} = \frac{exp(-\theta^Tx_i)}{1+exp(-\theta^Tx_i)}
$$

These expressions rely on the definition of the logistic/sigmoid function $\sigma(\theta^Tx_i) = \frac {1} {1+\exp(-\theta^Tx_i)}$ and let us state more concisely $\frac {exp(\theta^Tx_i)} {1+\exp(\theta^Tx_i)} = 1-\sigma(\theta^Tx_i)$

So the problem we are trying to solve goes from:
$$
\sum_i^m \left[x_i\cdot \frac {\exp\{-\theta^T x_i\}} {1+\exp\{-\theta^T x_i\}} - (y_i-1)  x_i \right]
$$

... and becomes -
$$
\sum_i^m \left[x_i\cdot (1-\sigma(\theta^T x_i)) - (y_i-1)  x_i \right]
$$
Factor out the vector, x_i
$$
\sum_i^m \left[ \left((1-\sigma(\theta^T x_i)) - (y_i-1)\right)  x_i \right]
$$

Resolve terms
$$
\sum_i^m \left[ \left(1-\sigma(\theta^T x_i) - y_i+1)\right)  x_i \right]
$$
$$
\sum_i^m \left[ \left(\sigma(\theta^T x_i) - y_i + 2)\right)  x_i \right]
$$

So, I have this 2 floating around. Did I do something wrong or is this just a term that vanishes when the hessian is calculated? I can't find any examples that are helping to clarify this for me.

Comment: What is $y_i$ in your notation? The gradient function should be $\sum_i (y_{ik} - t_{ik} ) \pmb{x}_i$ where $t_{ik}$ is the matrix representing the class of each input $\pmb{x}_i$ and $y_{ik}$ is the corresponding softmax. From this the Hessian should be fairly straightforward since only $y_{ik}$ depends on $\theta$. By the way is this model multiclass or binary?

Comment: The class would be binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a few variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
z &= X\t &&\qiq &dz = X\,d\t \\
e &= \exp(z), \;&E = {\rm Diag}(e) &\qiq &de = e\odot dz= E\,dz \\
p &= \frac{e}{\o+e}, &P = {\rm Diag}(p) &\qiq &dp = (P-P^2)\,dz \\
&&&\qiq&\;\,p=P\o \\
}$$
Write the cross-entropy $(\l)$ in terms of these variables,
then calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
-\l &= y:\log(p) \;+\; (\o-y):\log(\o-p) \\
-d\l &= y:P^{-1}\,\c{dp} \;+\; (\o-y):(I-P)^{-1}\,(-dp) \\
 &= y:P^{-1}\,\c{(P-P^2)\,dz} \;+\; (y-\o):(I-P)^{-1}(P-P^2)\,dz \\
 &= y:(I-P)\,dz \;+\; (y-\o):P\,dz \\
 &= (y-Py):\c{dz} \;+\; (Py-\c{P\o}):dz  \\
-d\l &= (y-\c{p}):\c{X\,d\t} \\
d\l &= X^T(p-y):d\t \\
g &=\frac{\p\l}{\p\t} = X^T(p-y) \\
}$$
The Hessian is much easier to calculate,
since everything except $p$ is a constant
$$\eqalign{
&dg = X^T\c{dp} \;=\; X^T(P-P^2)\,X\,d\t \\
&H\;=\;\frac{\p g}{\p\t} \;=\; X^T(P-P^2)\,X
\\
}$$

---

In the above, all functions are applied elementwise
and a colon denotes the matrix inner product
$$ A:B \;=\; {\rm trace}(A^TB) \;=\; B:A $$

Here's a quick derivation of the Logistic function
(using elementwise multiplication)
$$\eqalign{
dp
 &= \frac{(\o+e)\odot\c{de} - e\odot de}{(\o+e)\odot(\o+e)} \\
 &= \frac{(\o+e)\odot\c{e\odot dz}
  - e\odot e\odot dz}{(\o+e)\odot(\o+e)} \\
 &= \Big[p\odot dz - p\odot p\odot dz\Big] \\
 &= \left(P-P^2\right)dz
}$$

Comment: Neat. Shouldn't z be negative (or it's argument)?

Comment: @Jred Multiply the numerator and denominator of your $p$ expression by $\exp(z)\;$

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a binary logistic regression (a good reference on this is C. M. Bishop, "*Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*", Chapter 4, pp.205-206). We are given some feature vectors
which we denote as $x_{ij}$ ($i$ indexes vectors, $j$ indexes features). We are trying
to calibrate $\theta_j$; the probability of  feature vector $x_{ij}$ being part
of class 1 is,
$$
p_i = \frac{\exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right)}
{1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right)}
$$
If we use the cross-entropy error function,
\begin{equation}
E = - \sum_i \left( t_i \ln p_i  + (1- t_i) \ln (1-p_i)   \right)
\label{CE}  \tag{CE}
\end{equation}
where $t_i \in \{0,1\}$ then since,
$$
\ln p_i = \sum_j \theta_j x_{ij} - \ln \left( 1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right) \right)
$$
and,
$$
 \ln (1-p_i)    =
 - \ln \left( 1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right) \right)
$$
we can rewrite (\ref{CE}) as,
$$
E = -\sum_i  \left( t_i\sum_j  \theta_j x_{ij}
- \ln \left( 1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right) \right) \right)
$$
It follows that,
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \theta_j}
=
\sum_i (p_i-t_i) x_{ij}
$$
given that,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}
\ln \left( 1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right) \right)
& =
\frac{1}{1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right)}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}
\left( 1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right) \right) \\
& =
\frac{\exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right)}{1+ \exp\left(\sum_j \theta_j x_{ij}\right)} x_{ij} \\
& =p_i x_{ij}
\end{align}
Since $t_i$ and $x_{ij}$ are not functions of $\theta$,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial \theta_j \partial \theta_k}
=\sum_i x_{ij} \frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \theta_k}
$$
Using,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}= \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \frac{1}{1+e^x}
$$
we have,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial \theta_j \partial \theta_k}
=\sum_i x_{ij} x_{ik} p_i (1-p_i) 
$$